# Magento, getProductUrl() returning same url

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm working on showing x amount of related products on the shopping cart page.

Here is my current code

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
            $c = count($cart);
            if($c != 0) {
                $c = $c - 1;
                $rand = rand(0, $c);
                $i = 0;
                    foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
                        if($i == $c) {
                            $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
                            $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                            $product = $model->load($productId);
                            $allRelatedProductIds = $product->getRelatedProductIds();

                            $rc = count($allRelatedProductIds) - 1;
                            $rand = rand(0, $rc);
                            $relatedProduct = $model->load($allRelatedProductIds[$rand]);
                            echo "<div class='page-title'><h1>Maybe you would like to try one of these</h1></div>";
                     foreach($allRelatedProductIds as $prod) {
                                $p = $model->load($prod);
                                echo "<a href='".$p->getProductUrl()."'>";
                                echo "<div style='float:left; font-size:1.3em; width:33%; line-height:1.25; font-family:\"karlaregular\"'>";
                                echo "<img src='".Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($p, 'small_image')->resize(300,300) ."' style='width:100%; height:100%;'>";
                                echo "<h2 class='product-name' style='text-align:center;'>".$p->getName()."</h2>";
                                echo "<div class='pricebox' style='text-align:center;'><span class='regular-price'><span class='price'>£".number_format($p->getPrice(), 2)."</span></span></div>";                          
                                echo "</div>";
                                echo "</a>";
                            } 

                        }
                      $i++;
                    }
            }
```

This almost works 100% problem is that the $p->getProductUrl() is only being populated by the first product in the loop and gives the wrong url to all sequential products.

I cannot see any issues with the above and would someone to take a look.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using this if clause `if($i == $c)`? it seems that you can't access the other products with this clause.

Comment: the aim to is to randomly pick a product in the cart then just show thats related products. at present that just selects the last product in the cart while i'm setting the below up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        $c = count($cart);
        if($c != 0) {
            $c = $c - 1;
            $rand = rand(0, $c);
            $i = 0;
                foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
                    if($i == $c) {
                        $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
                        $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                        $product = $model->load($productId);
                        $allRelatedProductIds = $product->getRelatedProductIds();

                        $rc = count($allRelatedProductIds) - 1;
                        $rand = rand(0, $rc);
                        $relatedProduct = $model->load($allRelatedProductIds[$rand]);
                        echo "<div class='page-title'><h1>Maybe you would like to try one of these</h1></div>";
                 foreach($allRelatedProductIds as $prod) {
                            $p = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($prod);
                            echo "<a href='".$p->getProductUrl()."'>";
                            echo "<div style='float:left; font-size:1.3em; width:33%; line-height:1.25; font-family:\"karlaregular\"'>";
                            echo "<img src='".Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($p, 'small_image')->resize(300,300) ."' style='width:100%; height:100%;'>";
                            echo "<h2 class='product-name' style='text-align:center;'>".$p->getName()."</h2>";
                            echo "<div class='pricebox' style='text-align:center;'><span class='regular-price'><span class='price'>£".number_format($p->getPrice(), 2)."</span></span></div>";                          
                            echo "</div>";
                            echo "</a>";
                        } 

                    }
                  $i++;
                }
        }
```